# How to handle adding new item or delete existing one in React using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a list of products called work items stored on my Redux store and I want to add an action that adds new work item or remove existing one when user picks up a a work item from the ui.

What I have so far is this workItemReducer:

```
import {
    FETCH_WORKITEMS_BEGIN,
    FETCH_WORKITEMS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_WORKITEMS_FAILURE,
    SELECTED_WORKITEM
} from '../actions/workItemAction';

const initialState = {
    workItems: [{"name":'work 1'}, {"name":'work 2'}, {"name":'work 3'}],
    workItemsSelected: {},
    loading: false,
    error: null
};

export default function workItemReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_WORKITEMS_BEGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                error: null
            };

        case FETCH_WORKITEMS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                workItems: action.payload.workItems
            };

        case FETCH_WORKITEMS_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload.error,
                workItems: []
            };

        case SELECTED_WORKITEM:
            return {
                ...state,
                workItemsSelected: action.payload.workItem
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and the actions looks as below:

```
export const FETCH_WORKITEMS_BEGIN   = 'FETCH_WORKITEMS_BEGIN';
export const FETCH_WORKITEMS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_WORKITEMS_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_WORKITEMS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_WORKITEMS_FAILURE';
export const SELECTED_WORKITEM = 'SELECTED_WORKITEM';

export const fetchWorkItemsBegin = () => ({
    type: FETCH_WORKITEMS_BEGIN
});

export const fetchWorkItemsSuccess = workItems => ({
    type: FETCH_WORKITEMS_SUCCESS,
    payload: { workItems }
});

export const fetchWorkItemsFailure = error => ({
    type: FETCH_WORKITEMS_FAILURE,
    payload: { error }
});

export const selectedWorkItem = workItem => ({
    type: SELECTED_WORKITEM,
    payload: { workItem }
});
```

I have a container component that disptach or call these actions which I am a bit confused where the logic of adding a new one or removing existing one happens, either on the container/smart component or directly in the reducer.

Container component has this method:

```
 onWorkItemSelect = (workItem) => {
     this.props.dispatch(selectedWorkItem(workItem));
 };
```

Anyone can help on writing the logic of adding new or remove existing one and where that code should live?

Comment: It should be directly on the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

adding this to reducer works thou im not sure if all this code should remain into the reducer:

```
 case SELECTED_WORKITEM:
        let arr = [];

        if (containsObject(action.payload.workItem, state.workItemsSelected)) {
           arr = remove(state.workItemsSelected, action.payload.workItem);
        } else {
           arr = [...state.workItemsSelected, action.payload.workItem];
        }

        return {
            ...state,
            workItemsSelected: arr
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be done in the reducer

when adding one you could just spread the current array which you can get from the reducer state

```
const { workItems } = state;
const { workItem } = action.payload;
return {
    // ...other stuff to return
    workItems: [...workItems, workItem],
}
```

to delete one

```
const { workItems } = state;
const { workItem } = action.payload;
return {
    // ...other stuff to return
    workItems: workItems.filter(x => x.name === workItem.name),
}
```